# Use grep -f to get the exact number of lines from another file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a file 1 that looks like this:

```
rs1
rs1
rs2
rs11
```

And file 2 like this:

```
rs1 100
rs2 200
rs11 300
rs21 400
```

I want to get the exact match of file 1 in file 2 (that is the exact number of lines). My desired output:

```
rs1 100
rs1 100
rs2 200
rs11 300
```

But I am getting this:

```
rs1 100
rs2 200
rs11 300
```

This is the command I am using:

```
grep -w -f file1 file2
```

Also tried this:

```
grep '^rs\w\+$' file1 | sed 's/^/^/;s/$/\ /' | grep -f - file2
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the files in the same order? What happens when a line in file1 doesn't match the next line in file2?

Comment: I just tried that, join needs the files to be sorted.

Comment: I know. That's part of why I was asking. I also don't know how it will handle the second question. But if it does what you want then that's good.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your questions. But it looks like there is a problem with join using my files. My files have more than 100 million lines and even though I use sort first I am getting an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `join`

```
$join file1 file2
rs1 100
rs1 100
rs2 200
rs11 300
```

From `man join`

```
  join - join lines of two files on a common field
         For  each  pair of input lines with identical join fields, write a line
         to standard output.  The default join field is the first, delimited  by
         whitespace.
```

OR

using `awk`

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{line[$1]=$0; next} ($0 in line){print line[$0]}' file2 file1
rs1 100
rs1 100
rs2 200
rs11 300
```

Comment: @Javier2013 You are welcome :) Glad that i could help

Comment: This could also be done with `awk`, which wouldn't have the prerequisites of having `file1` and `file2` sorted, like `join` expects: `awk 'NR==FNR { value[$1] = $2 } NR!=FNR { print $1, value[$1] }' file2 file1`

Comment: When I tried to use join with my files (over 100 million lines) I got an error saying that the files are not sorted, even though I used sort before.

Comment: using awk worked for my bigger dataset. Answer accepted. Thanks again!

Comment: You could change the second clause to do something like `NR != FNR { if value[$1] print $1, value[$1] }` to skip entries from `file1` that don't have a match, or add an `else print $1, "no match"` or something along those lines if you prefer that... The original question didn't really specify what to do in the no-match case...

Comment: Yes @twalberg I just notice that I didn't specify that. My bad. Just checked your new reply. thanks!